# How to implement multiple attachments using Ruby on Rails Action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making a feature to allow user to attach multiple attachments while sending the email. I have added *multiple:true* and multipart:true  but am not been able to attach multiple attachments. Please help me how can I do that.
Also, please mention, how can I display the uploaded file names , 1 after another.
Note: I am using paperclip

My code:

Form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag mass_mail_reseller_path, :multipart => true, class: "new-mail-form form-horizontal" do%>
        <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="row form-group">
          <%= label_tag "attachment", 'Attachment:', class: "col-sm-1 control-label"%>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <%= file_field_tag "attachment",  multiple: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

my_controller.rb#action

```
def mail_reseller
    _from = params[:from]
    _to = get_resellers_mail_Ids(params[:to])
    _subject = params[:subject]
    _content = params[:body]
    if params[:attachment]
      _filename = params[:attachment].original_filename
      _file = params[:attachment].read
    end
    Resque.enqueue(ResellerWorker, _to, _from,  _subject, _content, _filename, _file)
    flash[:notice] = "Mail has been sent."
    redirect_to reseller_admin_path(:project_id => 'lead_tracking_reseller')
    # directory = "#{Rails.root}/files"
    # path = File.join(directory, _filename)
    # File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:attachment].read) }
  end
```

mailers/my_mailer.rb

```
def mass_mail_resellers _to, _from, _subject, _content, _filename, _file
    attachments[_filename] = _file if (_filename && _file)
    @mail_body = _content
    mail from: _from,
         to: _to,
         bcc: 'jam@company.com',
         subject: _subject
  end

model/resller.rb
class Reseller < User
  has_many :settlements
  belongs_to :account_manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'account_manager_id'
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'author_id'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :plans
  has_many :attachments
end
```

## ResellerWorker code.

reseller_worker.rb

```
class ResellerWorker
  @queue = :reseller_mail_queue
  include Redmine::I18n

  def self.perform(_to, _from, _subject, _content, _filename, _file)
    _to.each do |_reseller|
      ResellerMailer.mass_mail_resellers(_reseller, _from, _subject, _content, _filename, _file).deliver
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `ResellerWorker`?  Also, please note that Redis isn't a great place to hold the contents of a file of indeterminate size...

Comment: @PinnyM What is ResellerWorker? . There is no file or code like that in app.
Please let me know, what you need.
If you're asking me about the reseller model code, I updated that. Please check my updated question.

Comment: You have a line in the `mail_reseller` method that looks like this: `Resque.enqueue(ResellerWorker, _to, _from,  _subject, _content, _filename, _file)`

Comment: @PinnyM. Sorry to say, I do not have that line either similar code.

Comment: Do a text search on this page for ResellerWorker :)  It's there in your controller action.

Comment: @PinnyM . I was blind!. I apologize for my mistake. Its a new code base I just started exploring it. I updated the ResellerWorker code which is in reseller_worker.rb file. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @PinnyM Can you please help me on this!

Comment: The line `attachments[_filename] = _file if (_filename && _file)` assigns a single file attachment.  You'll need to pass multiple files as an array, and assign each one of them exactly this way.  However, you aren't well set up for passing these files since you're injecting them into the redis queue.  Consider storing them in a temp directory and passing an array of file paths to the queue instead.

Comment: @PinnyM Thanks for the clue. Can you please paste some sample implementation or code. My attachments are temporarily stored in **files** directory.

Comment: @PinnyM Can you please walk me through some sample code.I'll accept the answer and close this thread.